# Implementing multiple link tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-analytics

In adobe analytics for a liniking tracking I am using this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onClick="s.tl(this,'e','google', null,'navigate');return false"> test </a>
```

If I have many links in my code and I want to make the same for all of them how is it possible to use one fuction for the onClick event for all links I have in code?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'a', function() { s.tl(this,'e','google', null,'navigate'); return false; });`

Comment: @Tushar thank you for your comment. I tried to execute your line using a script under the <body>  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function() { s.tl(this,'e','link', null,'navigate'); return false; });
  
  </script> and in links links I have something like this <a href="www.google.com"> google </a> <a href="www.msn.com"> msn </a> but it is not working

Comment: it's not working because you need Jquery library to do that

Comment: @user2761073 I don't think the answer you accepted below is good for you (see my comment on the answer).  I can provide you a couple of solutions that make use of stuff already provided by Adobe Analytics, but first you need to clarify what it is you want to track, and also what version of the library you are using.  Based on context, I *assume* you want to track clicks on links that navigate the visitor off your site? Or were you wanting to track *all* link clicks?  What do you actually want to see in your reports?

Comment: @CrayonViolent the version of JQuery is v2.1.3. My concept is simple I have links in my html code and I want to use the s.tl() for all links with one command

Comment: @user2761073 okay but do you *really* want to pop exit link tracking hard-coded as "google" on *all* the links on your page, regardless of where they point to? If that's *really* what you want, then sure, **Michelem**'s answer will work, or you could simplify it with jQuery. p.s. - I was asking what Version of the *Adobe Analytics* library you are using, not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This should work with native javascript, without any external library needed

```
var links = document.links;

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    s.tl(this,'e','google', null,'navigate');return false
  });
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. It wholesale adds exit link tracking to *all* links on your site, and hardcodes them as "google" to boot..

Comment: He asked for "all links I have" I gave him what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can control your exit links a few different ways but a simple one would be to set s.linkInternalFilters.

```
s.linkInternalFilters = "javascript:" 
// will send all link clicks (except a "javascript" match) as exits 
s.linkInternalFilters = "javascript:,my-site.com" 
// will send all link clicks (except a "javascript" match or "my-site.com") as exits.
```